# VS Code: from (file) import * not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm having the config.py and main.py in the same folder. However, when I try to use `from config import *`, it would not work and I can access the variables stored in `config.py`. I'm using python 3.11 from Microsoft Store. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Instead of using `from config import *`, either import the specific variable names or just use `import config`, and update your references in main.py to those variables to explicitly reference `config.varname`.  Using `from config import *` pollutes your local namespace and can lead to difficult to detect bugs.

Answer (score 0):

like [nigh-anxiety](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17030540/nigh-anxiety) already mentioned in the comments, it is a really bad practice to import * from something because it can pollute your name space ...

another problem could arise if you have a libary called config which will lead to problems

Best practice would be:

```
from config import my_var
```

or if you want everything

```
import config
print(config.my_var)
```

important is that the code is in your working directory for imports to work fine else there could be problems ...

and to use

```
config.my_var
```

instead of

```
my_var
```

is not that big of a deal and will help you keep your namespace clean